Laptop goes to standby too fast
So, I've been dealing with this issue for a while, and it's nothing major I believe but it does bother me when it happens...
I have a Lenovo Yoga 720 on which I currently boot Ubuntu 22.04 from an external drive (created using this guide).
As I believe is common, I often leave it idle when not working with it and it obviously goes into standby according to the timing I've set.
The issue is that, from time to time, after waking it up from standby the timeout set to return to standby again is lower, about 30s I'd say. Like, I stop moving the mouse while checking code, and the entire screen goes to black!
I've tried searching info online, but with no luck:

a post mentioned issues in the behavior with the lid recognition, but everything seems fine on that end (systemd-logind.service running, logging correctly if I open/close the lid for real, nothing shown after it goes black)
journalctl does not log anything when the screen goes to black
power-related settings are fine (or seems to be) and not touched when this happens

Unfortunately I don't know what else to check. Any idea or suggestion or even shot in the dark, so to speak, are welcome!
EDIT: Forgot to mention that the only way for me to go back to normal behavior is to restart the system!
Some info on my env:
slim71@slim71-Ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
slim71@slim71-Ubuntu:~$ uname -r
6.5.0-28-generic


